# Adding to a parameter in a method call, outside of parameter parentheses?

Tags: ruby, methods, parameters

I saw this line of code in a test I'm trying to get to pass.

```
  stack = Overflow.at(10) + 3
```

I've never seen a method called like this. Every book/blog I've seen only shows what's happening inside the parentheses (like the splat operator, multiple params, etc). I've never seen something added to a method call, outside the parentheses, and I can't even figure out how to word what's happening to look it up to research/learn.

Any help on what exactly is happening, even if it's just what exactly this is technique is called for me to research, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Overflow.at(10)` is executed, 3 is added to the result. Nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Overflow.at(10) returns int you may treat

```
stack = Overflow.at(10) + 3
```

as shorten version of:

```
overflow = Overflow.at(10)
stack = overflow  + 3
```

It's more compact, but the result is the same.

Comment: I think I was confused because `overflow = Overflow.at(10)` returns a String, not an int. So I was pretty baffled at the `+` operator after the parameter like that since you can't add a String to an Int and thought maybe the `+3` part was just appending to the parameter. Just FYI, with the line `overflow = Overflow.at(10) + 3`, if I then call `overflow.to_s` it returns a string like `"10:03"`